# git commit error : name consists only of disallowed characters:

Tags: git

create a new git project and only add README.txt
when I commit, an error occurred.

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the contents of `git config  user.name`. Also it's better to copy and paste the actual text. Images of text aren't very useful. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: Is it difficult to copy the text from the window and paste it **as text** in the question?

Comment: Thank U very much!
I find it's because my user.name is '.' before.
now I change it and the issue is disappeared.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Problem here seems to be your username. Check it with `git config --list`.
You can change it with

> $ git config --global user.name "validName"

Comment: This is also the case if you have a special character in your *Full Name* in /etc/passwd, for example, as a result of pressing `Esc` during *Full Name* entry of `adduser` command -- whilst not having any git-specific `user.name` configured. The solution in that case is to clean up your *Full Name* in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific,
*1) git config --local --list* 
Check your local config for this local repo, with the command above 
Look for the user.name and user.email, 
user.name =  
user.email = 
If you see the following,
meaning they're empty

Type: 
*2) git config --local user.name  ['user name']* 
*3) git config --local user.email ['user@gmail.com']*

Explanation: 
**By typing following 2nd and 3rd command you're setting your local config, which means the commits from your local repo will be made from this user name and email on Github**

**By doing that you're able to contribute to remote Repo as a different user from different user.name and user.email**

**If you don't specify --global or --local config , you'll end up having this issue,** 
**However having one of them works fine, as long as you identified yourself as someone**

**It shouldn't be empty, bc it's not allowed to commit as an UNKOWN USER  on github, so make sure you specify, by which name you're contributing**